# Why xdebug doesn't recognise localhost, only recognises 127.0.0.1

Tags: php, debugging, intellij-idea, xdebug

I am facing this problem when i am trying to debug my web application. The page can load whether i am using 127.0.0.1 or localhost, but the breakpoint only works for 127.0.0.1. I am using Intellij and MAMP. My php.ini configuration is as follows:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.10/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port="9000"
xdebug.remote_log="/Applications/MAMP/xdebug_log.txt"
```

I have also tried to add

```
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
```

but it makes no difference, the same problem still persist. My hosts file is as follows:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Also when i want to do debug the html page, i have to do this on the main php file, eg to debug index.html, i have to do this:

```
http://127.0.0.1/<the_folder>/index.php?xdebug_session_start=intellij
```

Sometimes it works and sometimes it don't! I have to try a few times to make it work. Sometimes would mean try various projects or try just debugging the php script only using "Debug" in Intellij. I only added "PHP Script" configuration, that is to debug just the php alone. There is this "PHP Web Application" configuration too... which does what i did above, but doesn't resolve my problem.

[image]

In summary:
1) Why do xdebug has problem resolving "localhost" for debugging?
2) How to I debug my php scripts loaded in my web application html file effectively?